# Ein deutscher Buchverlag, wie Penguin books?

Tags: resource, book

Also ich bin ein 20-jähriger und wohne seit einem Jahr in Deutschland. Mittlerweile besuche ich ein Gymnasium und habe noch zwei Jahre bis zum Abitur. Ich möchte ein paar Empfehlung bekommen.

Welche Buchverlage, die man mit Penguin Books vergleichen kann, würdet ihr empfehlen?

Ich nenne Penguin Books Classics, weil deren englische Bücher am Ende diese Anmerkungen haben, wo viele Begriffe und Historisches usw. erklärt werden, was dem Leser sehr hilft. Z.B. *The Republic* von *Platon*.

Comment: In Deutschland gibt es die Bücher aus der Reclam-Reihe, normalerweise erkennbar an ihrem kleinen Format und der gelben Farbe. Die sind auch normalerweise voll von Fußnoten und anderen Anmerkungen.

Comment: @Marcel - Das wäre eigentlich eine vollwertige Antwort gewesen.

Comment: Es gibt auch von wichtigen Werken der Literatur kommentierte Ausgaben, aber vielleicht nicht so sehr gedacht für den Gebrauch durch Schüler. Vor ca. einem Jahr erschienen: die erste ordentlich kommentierte und annotierte Ausgabe von Hitlers "Mein Kampf". Aber das ist vermutlich nicht, was du mit Penguin-Büchern meintest...

Comment: Penguin has a varied program (and I am not even referring to the Bojack autobiography https://youtu.be/65k_F-CRDBk), maybe you are particularly thinking particularly of Penguin Classics.

Comment: @CarstenS yes exactly, I mean Penguin Classics

Comment: Hast du schonmal deinen Deutschlehrer gefragt? Er sollte dein Sprachlevel gut einschaetzen koennen und darueber hinaus Erfahrung mit der Auswahl geeigneter Literatur haben.

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt den [Deutschen Klassikerverlag](http://www.suhrkamp.de/deutscher-klassiker-verlag_69.html). Dort gibt es immer sehr sorgfältig zusammengestellte Anmerkungen.